# Getting Type Error: Can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple

Tags: python, integer, tuples, typeerror, args

**PROBLEM:**
I am not understanding where am I getting wrong and where should I correct my code. If anyone gets the solution please help.

***MY CODE:***

```
def myfunc(*args):
    #take entries
    my_list=list()
    formula=2*(args)+5
    #make loop for entering in formula
    for i in args:
        print('{}/n'.format(formula))
    return formula
```

**ERROR:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last)

----> 1 myfunc([2,4,5])

in myfunc(*args)
      2     #take entries
      3     my_list=list()
----> 4     formula=2*(args)+5
      6     for i in args:
      7       return formula

TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple
```

Comment: What is your function supposed to do?

Comment: `args` is a tuple, multiplying it by a number yields another tuple. You can't add numbers to tuples with `+`. Hence the error

Comment: What are you trying to do? What does your function do, whats the expected output?

Comment: My function is designed to take multiple inputs of the same variable at the same time and give its corresponding value using the given formula.

Comment: Thank you all for helping but I found the solution:                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  def myfunc(*args):
    my_list=list(args) 
    for i in my_list:
        formula=2*(i)+5
        print('(x,y)=({},{})'.format(i,formula))